# Kiwi test of ReactiveCocoa produce EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: reactive-cocoa, kiwi

I'm trying to test ReactiveCocoa code with Kiwi framework.

Here is code :

```
-(void)bindParentModel:(FEPVehiclePropertyModel*)theParentModel{
self.parentModel = theParentModel;
[RACObserve(self, parentModel.currentName) subscribeNext:^(NSString* modelName) {
    self.avaliableVales = [FEPVehiclePropertyValuesContainer possibleVlauesForKey:modelName];
    if (![self.avaliableVales containsObject:self.currentName]){
        self.currentName = [self.avaliableVales firstObject];
    }
}];
}
```

Here is test case

```
it(@"check vehicle model binding", ^{
    NSArray* carModel =  [FEPVehiclePropertyValuesContainer  possibleVlauesForKey:@"2013"];
    FEPVehiclePropertyModel* model = [[FEPVehiclePropertyModel alloc] init];
    FEPVehiclePropertyModel* parenModel = [[FEPVehiclePropertyModel alloc] init];
    parenModel.parentModel = nil;
    parenModel.avaliableVales = carModel;
    parenModel.currentName = [carModel lastObject];
    [model bindParentModel:parenModel];
    parenModel.currentName = [parenModel.avaliableVales firstObject];
    [[model.currentName should] equal:@"2.0L GTDI EcoBoost 6-speed manual"];
});
```

Every time i run test case i've got a EXC_BAD_ACCESS at RACKVOTrampoline class when it tries 
to add observer

```
    [self.target addObserver:self forKeyPath:self.keyPath options:options context:&RACKVOWrapperContext];
```

Any suggestions?

Production code works with ReactiveCocoa just fine.

Comment: Have you tried to run the same piece with debugging? Seems like something is deallocated prematurely.